# An adjective to describe the benefits associated with saving time

Tags: adjectives, time

I'm looking for an adjective to replace 'time saving' in the following sentence:

"...a range of immediate and tangible **time-saving** and economic benefits"

I'm thinking it should be something like 'efficiency' or 'productivity' but they don't quite sound right next to 'benefits' in this context.

May just change it to read "...a range of immediate and tangible benefits, saving time and money", but interested to see if anyone can come up with something better :-)

Thanks for **your** time!

Comment: Any particular reason why you have an aversion to _time-saving_? Is the hyphen bothersome? (If so, you might consider the unhyphenated version: [_timesaving_](http://www.onelook.com/?w=timesaving).)

Comment: In the original version *benefits* is preceded by too many descriptors— *immediate, tangible, time-saving, economic*. It makes for a congested sentence. Your revised version is better and reads more like plain English.

Answer (score 1):

Efficient:
1. performing or functioning effectively with the least waste of "time" and effort;

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/efficient

Comment: The trouble with this adjective is that it implies savings, other than time , like money, manpower, heat e.t.c.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

*advantageus* and *valuable*

http://thesaurus.com/browse/Time-saving